# Checkboxes + Listviews Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, list, mobile, checkbox

I am getting data for a listview via ajax,

```
$('#list').append('<li><a id=\"' + json[i].userID + '\">'+json[i].name+'</a></li>').trigger('create');
```

I want each item to also have a checkbox and want to be able to get the individual checkbox value of each list item. I have no idea how to approach this, and would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you would start by appending a checkbox item along with your data, and give that some value (I'll just use your `json[i].name` value per checkbox) and a class as well (for handler purposes):

```
$('#list').append('<li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="' + json[i].name + '" class="appendedBox"/>
    <a id=\"' + json[i].userID + '\">'+json[i].name+'</a>
    </li>').trigger('create');
});
```

And now you can delegate a handler for you new checkboxes:

```
$("#list").on("change", ".appendedBox", function() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Comment: ok this makes sense, but is there a way that I can send every single checkbox value via php? Should I put the list inside a form?